# Multiline text field content is missing in display form

Tags: list, event-receivers, display-form

I have created `ItemAdded` event. It will add multiple users in `users and group` column of custom list.

After complete this event, when i open display form, multiline text column value is missing.

Anyone face this type of issue? Any Idea?

Comment: Try enabling the version history to track whether there was any value in the filed originally. There isnt enough info in your question to udnerstand the problem

Comment: Thanks for reply @HarryB. If i open edit form. content will be there. Problem is only in display form. It is caused by item.update() in event receiver,